# Defining all values for $X$ on trigonometric functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So having a bit of a hard time understanding this part of the problem, I'm asked to graph $y = -3\tan(\pi x + 5\pi)$

So first I have to find if it's defined for all values of $x$... and I can't divide by zero. But here's where I am confused, the correct answer is:

Defined for all values of $x$ except: $\{\pi/2, 3\pi/2, 5\pi/2...\}$

So why? Is there a formula you're supposed to do? The book I am using literally just comes to this conclusion and doesn't show me why.

Look I'm not like asking for homework help here. I don't know why I was downvoted but I'm seriously just trying to understand this. This question had nothing to do with any homework I have. I would take the downvote if someone would explain what's going on?

Comment: Don't take the downvotes personally; it happens on this site sometimes. I've seen blatantly obvious attempts at getting hw answers on here get upvoted way past posts like yours. I offered an explanation to your question below.

Comment: WHy don't you start showing that $\tan(a+5\pi)=\tan(a)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $$-3\tan(\pi x + 5\pi) =-3\frac{\sin(\pi x + 5\pi)}{\cos(\pi x + 5\pi)} $$ so we run into trouble when $$\cos(\pi x + 5\pi)=0$$ Cosine returns $0$ when the input is an odd integer multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, like $3\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $5\frac{\pi}{2}$. In general, $$\cos(y) =0 \quad \text{whenever} \quad y =\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}, \space n \in \Bbb{Z}$$ and hence

Comment: Ok so this is starting to make sense, but how do we know when cos(πx + 5π) = 0? Is there some formula I can do with that to figure that out?

Comment: Actually I understand when cos(π/2) = 0, but I guess where I am confused is that we are trying to see when cos(πx + 5π) = 0, so x would be π/2, and it wouldn't be zero? Or am i thinking of this wrong?

Comment: $x$ would need to be $1/2$ because if $x = \pi/2$ then π$x= $π(π/2) $= \pi^2/2$. You just need $$\pi x+5\pi = \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} \\ \implies x+5=\frac{2n+1}{2} \\ \implies x = \frac{2n-9}{2}$$ and $2n-9$ is still an arbitrary odd integer

Comment: I think I get it now actually, we are only seeing when the function relevant to that equation is equal to 0, then it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in the question. It should read: $$y=-3 \tan(x+5\pi)$$ (too many $\pi$'s)

In any case, the $\tan$ function is undefined for $\frac{\pi}2\pm k\pi$ for any whole number $k$.

Comment: No that's the question. and why is the tan function undefined for that? I need to know so when I do problems in the future I can have a way to check my work as to why it is.

Comment: There is DEFINITELY a mistake in the question. $-3\tan(\pi x+5\pi)$ is defined at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: this was a while ago but there is no mistake in the question, I hate to break it to you. It was taken from a software that is used at thousands of universities. Maybe you read it wrong?

Comment: also "−3tan(πx+5π) is defined at x=π/2" yes I said that already.

Comment: Well I hate to tell you this, but that "software that is used at thousands of universities" is wrong. The function is undefined at ${x=\frac12,\frac32,\frac52,\dots}$ (i.e. with out the $\pi$'s)

Comment: Ohhh okay. the software is wrong.. right. *wink wink*

Comment: I don't even think you get it anyways. This is like weeks old I don't even remember much from it so can't give too much detail, but the software isn't wrong maybe you're just not understanding the question right, seeing as other people have answered it and they were correct. Notice how you're the only one claiming this?